# bad access in C++ where the variables in the for loops are not staying within given limits

Tags: c++

So this is a method to iterate through a matrix of chars to find specific words in a dictionary file. The current problem is a bad access indicated below.... what is causing this is that d2 = like a million and l also equals a value in the hundreds of thousands.... however, my limits are clearly not even close to that.....

```
void Puzzle:: algorithm2(){
    int numberofwords = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r<Rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c<Columns; c++){
            for (int d1 = -1; d1<=1; d1++){
                for (int d2 = -1; d2<=1; d2++){
                    //42 ~ 30(2)^0.5
                    for (int l = dictionary.getminlength(); l<30; l++) {
                        if (d1==d2==0){
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if ((r+(d1*l))>30||(c+(d2*l))>30||(c+(d2*l))<0||(r+(d1*l))<0){
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            string tempword = "";
                            for (int p = 0; p<l+1; p++) {
                                tempword[p] = TheBoard[r+(d1*p)][c+(d2*p)];//badacces
                                if(dictionary.BinarySearch(tempword)){
                                    cout << "Found " << tempword << " at (" << r << "," << c << ") to (" << r+d1*(int)tempword.length() << "," << c+d2*(int)tempword.length() << ")" << endl;
                                    numberofwords++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << numberofwords << "words" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is `d1==d2==0` ?

Comment: Why is it in the inner for() loop although d1 and d2 should not change there?

Comment: d1 and d2 are the direction the search for the word in the matrix... d1 is the rows and d2 is the columns. I dont want when they are both 0 because that is the beginning of the word.

Comment: I think @MM. means the expression, not your intent.  You would want `d1 == 0 && d2 == 0` (obviously they're equal to each other in that's true).  With what you have now, think about what it means for the subexpression `d2 == 0` to be true, and how the result of that expression would compare to d1, i.e. `d1 == result`.